# I have 404 answer In some of my Wordpress Posts

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, elementor

I use wordpress and i have troubles with the permalinks here, I have more than 3000 post in that wordpress and some of them are working and others are showing 404 page, I tryed this things so please dont tell me to test this again:

1. Disable all plugins
2. Change Theme for default one
3. Change Permalinks for default one
4. Change the .htaccess
5. Change the DB
6. Generate the posts again
7. Change something in Apache2 (AllowOverride All, .....)
8. Regenerating the permalinks

(SOLUTION)
Install plugin Permalink Manager Lite for Wordpress and go to Settings -> Regenerate/Reset

Comment: Did you try not changing, but regenerating the permalinks? To do this, just navigate to `/wp-admin/options-permalink.php`, don't select another option, but just click Save Changes. Other than that, it's impossible to guess why 'some posts' work, and others don't. You could identify a few that return a 404, search for them under Posts and compare their permalink against the link that returned a 404.

Comment: Yes I Tryed but no results